# How to retrieve data via a while loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am looping through a MySQL result but I am running into an issue. The issue is that only my first `if` statement is being executed. The rest of my `if` statements are returning empty strings. What is confusing me is this: When I remove the first if statement in the while loop, the next if statement will return data but all other statements below it will not.

Here is my relevant code:

```
// Get Addresses
$queryAddresses  = "SELECT * FROM contact_addresses WHERE contact_id = $contactID";
$resultAddresses = mysqli_query($dbc, $queryAddresses);
$numAddresses    = mysqli_num_rows($resultAddresses);

if ($numAddresses >= 1) {
    $address_labels = '';
    $addresses      = '';
    while ($address = mysqli_fetch_array($resultAddresses, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $address_labels .= $address['label'].'<br>';

        if (!empty($address['address'])) {
            $address = $address['address'].', ';
        } else {
            $address = '';
        }
        
        /* ALL OF THE IF STATEMENTS BELOW THIS LINE RETURN EMPTY STRINGS EVEN THOUGH THE INFORMATION IS STORED IN THE DATABASE.  */
        if (!empty($address['address_two'])) {
            $address_two = $address['address_two'].', ';
        } else {
            $address_two = '';
        }

        if (!empty($address['city'])) {
            $city = $address['city'].', ';
        } else {
            $city = '';
        }

        if (!empty($address['state'])) {
            $state = $address['state'].', ';
        } else {
            $state = '';
        }

        if (!empty($address['zip'])) {
            $zip = $address['zip'].', ';
        } else {
            $zip = '';
        }

        if (!empty($address['country'])) {
            $country = $address['country'].', ';
        } else {
            $country = '';
        }

        $addresses .= $address.''.$address_two.''.$city.''.$state.''.$zip.''.$country.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you frame the same logic with if else if else i guess it will resolve your issue.

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia I thought the same thing but in this scenario I do not see a way of doing that. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the line `$address = $address['address'].', ';` you are replacing the `$address` array with the new string and wiping out the array. Try changing the string variable name:

```
    if (!empty($address['address'])) {
        $address_one = $address['address'].', ';
    } else {
        $address_one = '';
    }

    if (!empty($address['address_two'])) {
        $address_two = $address['address_two'].', ';
    } else {
        $address_two = '';
    }

    if (!empty($address['city'])) {
        $city = $address['city'].', ';
    } else {
        $city = '';
    }

    if (!empty($address['state'])) {
        $state = $address['state'].', ';
    } else {
        $state = '';
    }

    if (!empty($address['zip'])) {
        $zip = $address['zip'].', ';
    } else {
        $zip = '';
    }

    if (!empty($address['country'])) {
        $country = $address['country'].', ';
    } else {
        $country = '';
    }

    $addresses .= $address_one.''.$address_two.''.$city.''.$state.''.$zip.''.$country.'<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($address = mysqli_fetch_array($resultAddresses, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $address_labels .= $address['label'].'<br>';

    if (!empty($address['address'])) {
        $address = $address['address'].', ';
    } else {
        $address = '';
    }
}
```

What I found while going through your code is you are using the same variable `$address` for the while loop as well as the first if statement. Try changing the loop variable, say `$result` and try

Answer (score 0):

```
Plz paste following Code in your editor:
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "databasename";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["first_name"]. " " . $row["last_name"]. "<br>";
        $fnanem ="";
        $lnanem ="";
        if(!empty($row["first_name"])){
            $fnanem = $row["first_name"];
        }else{
            $fnanem = "";
        }

        if(!empty($row["last_name"])){
            $lnanem = $row["last_name"];
        }else{
            $lnanem = "";
        }

        echo $fnanem."---->".$lnanem."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following code change the variable, as it is replacing the values of the array by assigning new value.

```
 if (!empty($address['address'])) {
        $address = $address['address'].', ';//Chang variable name here
    } else {
        $address = '';//Chang variable name here
    }
```